# Django, client sent cookie is lost in server

Tags: django, session

We set "Cookie" header when we send an ajax request from client (android Ion library)

Most of times, django picks up the cookie with `request.COOKIES`.
However sometimes, sent cookie (`sessionid` in the cookie) is not found in `request.COOKIES`

What are the possible reasons?

I'm having trouble to find where `request.COOKIES` gets set in Django code base...

Comment: [It gets set here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2fcafd169b5fcf4bb6711ca8aa4d59d80225ec7a/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py#L135).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by @solarissmoke this is done in the wsgi handler, by parsing the Cookies header (from the attribute `environ['HTTP_COOKIES']`).

The common culprits could be, well, any application that can modify the request on the way, from your http/proxy server, to django middleware to your own view code.

Another common fail point when setting cookies in client side, is that standard cookies are domain specific, and browsers have settings to allow/prevent setting cookies outside the current server domain (e.g from Response objects); or even disallow any cookies whatsoever. Here is [the Google Chrome documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1) on how to manage (and block) cookies on any platform.

To debug, I suggest you log (e.g print out) the request.META (which should contain the `HTTP_COOKIES` environ key) at different stages of your app. You could conditionally log the whole request, with something like this:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('my_app')


def my_view(request):
    if not request.COOKIES:
        logger.error('Cookies empty! HttpRequest.META is: %s', dict(request.META))
```

You should of course handle scenarios when clients do not allow storing cookies, possibly showing an error page, if session cookies are crucial to your application.